# Pendulum with a spring simulation in Java

Tags: java, simulation

How can I get pendulum with double springs simulation to work? I only got the spring but it doesn't work with pendulum; it only moves forward and all.
My task:
I get two springs and I must to simulate a pendulum with these two springs something like that:
[example](http://www.physics.ucla.edu/demoweb/demomanual/harmonic_motion_and_waves/simple_harmonic_motion/smhrmt09s.gif)
My code:

```
public class Springs {

    private static Spring spring = new Spring();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(spring);
                frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Start") {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        spring.start();
                    }
                }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                spring.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class Spring extends JComponent {

        private static final int SIZE = 500;
        private static final int DELAY = 1000 / 20; // ~20Hz
        private final Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
        private final FloatSpring fs = new FloatSpring(42);
        private final int target = 0;
        private final float delta = 1f / SIZE;
        private float elapsed = 0f;
        private Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if ((int) fs.getPosition() < (target + 1)) {
                    timer.stop();
                    return;
                }
                elapsed += delta;
                fs.update(target, elapsed);
                repaint();
            }
        });

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = (getWidth() - icon.getIconWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (int) fs.getPosition();
            icon.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
            int xc = x + icon.getIconWidth() / 2;
            g.drawLine(xc, 0, xc, y);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(SIZE / 2, SIZE);
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.stop();
            elapsed = 0;
            fs.setPosition(SIZE - icon.getIconHeight());
            fs.setVelocity(0);
            timer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

and FloatSpring:

```
    public class FloatSpring {

  float position;

  float springK;

  float dampingK;

  float velocity;

  public FloatSpring(float springK, float dampingK) {
    super();
    this.position = 0;
    this.springK = springK;
    this.dampingK = dampingK;
    this.velocity = 0;
  }

  public FloatSpring(float springK) {
    this (springK, (float)(2 * Math.sqrt(springK)));    
  }


  public void update(float target, float time) {

    //Set v to target - position, this is the required movement
    float v = position - target;

    //Multiply displacement by spring constant to get spring force,
    //then subtract damping force
    v = v * -springK - velocity * dampingK;

    //v is now a force, so assuming unit mass is is also acceleration.
    //multiply by elapsed time to get velocity change
    velocity += v * time;

    //If velocity isn't valid, zero it
    if (Float.isNaN(velocity) || Float.isInfinite(velocity)) {
      velocity = 0;
    }

    //Change the roll at the new velocity, for elapsed time
    position += velocity * time;
  }


  public float getDampingK() {
    return dampingK;
  }

  public void setDampingK(float dampingK) {
    this.dampingK = dampingK;
  }

  public float getPosition() {
    return position;
  }

  public void setPosition(float position) {
    this.position = position;
  }

  public float getSpringK() {
    return springK;
  }

  public void setSpringK(float springK) {
    this.springK = springK;
  }

  public float getVelocity() {
    return velocity;
  }

  public void setVelocity(float velocity) {
    this.velocity = velocity;
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for you to get help if you reduced amount of code needed to go through (e.g. remove irrelevant comments and only post parts of code you know don't work)

Comment: i dont know what i need to change, only begginer on Java devs..sorry